# Updated to webpack 5, have not been able to debug any ts or js files

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Today I was having issues with my angular dependencies in my package.json, so I decided to update them all. In doing so, I went from webpack v4 to webpack v5. I didn't realize that I would lose compatibility with crypto-js. Upon scowering here and google, I finally came up with the following files.

**My current issue:** Everything is working great, except for the following problems:

1. ts files do not load in the dev tools.
2. My debugger statements do not load. (Only way to debug is with breakpoint)
3. I cannot debug my js/ts files in Visual Studio 2019 with any of the tutorials posted.

Please enlighten me with what I am doing wrong here. All help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "royal_competition",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "echo Starting... && ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:production": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build:ssr": "ng run royal_competition:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "12.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.9",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.14.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.0.9",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "stream": [
        "node_modules/stream-browserify"
      ],
      "crypto": [
        "node_modules/crypto-browserify"
      ]
    },
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json (the only important part):

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
            },
            "progress": true,
```

custom-webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    filename: "static/js/[name].js"
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify")
    },
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      moduleFilenameTemplate: 'file:///[absolute-resource-path]',
      sourceRoot: ''
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Well >so I decided to update them all< is where the problem happened. Just rollback the changes and update only the deps that need updating.

Comment: There were a lot of breaking changes between the versions because I admittedly do not know how to manage them properly.